# AngularJs ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, singlepage

I trying to add a custom filter, but if I use the following code:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

But if I do so, I get: "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" in firebug.

The rest of application is working fine, I am using ng-app in a tag div not in tag html, and https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.js

Comment: have you referenced `app/js/filters.js` ?

Comment: do you mean include some angular js file or put the code inside of filter.js?

Comment: "In order to create a new filter, you are going to create a phonecatFilters module and register your custom filter with this module:" http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the angular.js script? Can you provide a jsfiddle with an example?

Comment: Well, finally I realize the problem. This is a single page with legacy code. I was injecting angular in a ajax partial page. If you have the same problem, put the angular.js in the base html and do workround with the $scope. Cheers and tks to every one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well in the way this is a single page application, the solution used was:

load the content with AJAX, like any other controller, and then call:

```
angular.bootstrap($('#your_div_loaded_in_ajax'),["myApp","other_module"]);
```

Comment: what is "other_module"?

Comment: an example of calling other module

Answer (score 47):

You should put the include angular line first, before including any other js file

Comment: @lborgav because Angular needs to load before it is utilized.  Hence if you don't put it at the top, a reference error will occur.

Answer (score 10):

I faced similar issue due to local vs remote referencing

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.js"></script>
```

As ui-grid.js is dependent on angular.js, ui-grid requires angular.js by the time its loaded. But in the above case, ui-grid.js [locally saved reference file] is loaded before angularjs was loaded [from internet],

> The problem was solved if I had both angular.js and ui-grid referenced
>   locally and as well declaring angular.js before ui-grid

```
<script src="lib/js/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="lib/js/ui-grid/3.0.7/ui-grid.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also found this to be my solution
I use 
"angular.min.js"  and "angular-route.min.js" from cdn https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/ 
and ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js from cdnjs.cloudflare.com, 
When using only local references it works as expected

Answer (score 5):

Always make sure that js file (angular.min.js) is referenced first in the HTML file. For example:

----------------- This reference will **THROW** error -------------------------

```
< script src="otherXYZ.js"></script>
< script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

----------------- This reference will **WORK** as expected -------------------

```
< script src="angular.min.js"></script>
< script src="otherXYZ.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

As @bmleite already mentioned in the comments, you probably forgot to load angular.js.

If I create a fiddle with angular directives in it, but don't include angular.js I get the exact same error in the Chrome console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

In case you'd happen to be using rails and the angular-rails gem then the problem is easily corrected by adding this missing line to application.js (or what ever is applicable in your situation):

```
//= require angular-resource
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because I made a copy-and-paste of ngBoilerplate into my project on a Mac without Finder showing hidden files.  So .bower was not copied with the rest of ngBoilerplate.  Thus bower moved resources to bower_components (defult) instead of vendor (as configured) and my app didn't get angular.  Probably a corner case, but it might help someone here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will happen if you'll use 'async defer' for  (the file that contains the filter) while working with angularjs:

```
<script src="js/filter.js" type="text/javascript" async defer></script>
```

if you do, just remove 'async defer'.

Answer (score 0):

If you've downloaded the angular.js file from Google, you need to make sure that Everyone has **Read access** to it, or it will not be loaded by your HTML file. By default, it seems to download with *No access* permissions, so you'll also be getting a message such as:

> GET http://localhost/myApp/js/angular.js

This maddened me for about half an hour!