# What is the cause for "angular is not defined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm following the video tutorials on [egghead.io](http://www.egghead.io/) but while trying to follow his example when he created a factory (see video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXpHV5gWgyk&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7)) I keep getting "angular is not defined" Reference Error but I have included the angular script

This is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-ng-app="">

        <div data-ng-controller="FirstController">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
        </div>



        <div data-ng-controller="SecondController">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="data.message">
            <h1>{{ data.message }}</h1>
        </div>


    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript file "main.js":

```
//Services
    // step 1 create an app                             
    var myApp = angular.module('Data', []).
    // tep 2 create factory
                // Service name, function
    myApp.factory('Data', function(){
        return { message: "I'm Data from a Service" }
    });



//Controllers
    function FirstController($scope, Data){
        $scope.data = Data;
    }

    function SecondController($scope){

    }
```

I have read a few posts where similar happen ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260399/angularjs-referenceerror-angular-is-not-defined)) and please correct me if I'm wrong but I think it is to do with Boot strapping andI have tried manually bootstrapping using `angular.bootstrap(document, ['Data']);` but with no success, still get same error.

But What I want to know is, Why this works for so many examples online, like the egghead video series, but I have issues as I believe I have followed his video very closely. is it a change in angular in recent versions?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You have to put your script tag after the one that references Angular. Move it out of the `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

The way you've set it up now, your script runs before Angular is loaded on the page.

Comment: Thank you, a silly mistake on my part much appreciated , I will except your answer once it allows me to

Comment: I ran into the same problem. It is caused by egghead in one video having the angular.min.js defined at the bottom of the page, and then in another video it is moved to the header in top the where main.js is defined.

Comment: Mine was a very silly mistake. I did not have link to the `angular.js` file  on the html file. I had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have not placed the script tags for angular js

you can do so by using cdn or downloading the angularjs for your project and then referencing it

after this you have to add your own java script in your case main.js

that should do

Comment: You didn't try doing this, did you?

Comment: sorry dude my bad i missed out on the last <script> tag :P

Would it not be better if we keep our script tags together(keeping script tags in the beginning and in the end also) . 

either keep them in the top or at the bottom ,  its better to keep in the bottom as doing so will first let your page load and then all your scripts will load.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as deke. I forgot to include the most important script: angular.js :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```