# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined using type script

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, typescript1.4, typescript1.5

I am working with Type Script and Angular js I have implemented a Controller which names as quick search and from that i am trying to perform search opeartions .I which i am getting the search term in a text box from my aspx and than on ng click it will goes to my controller and than it will Put data into web api method and than return resuts in to grid.
But i am facing problem because of 
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
 i have written my controller code below:-

```
/// <reference path="../interface/interface.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
module CustomerSearch.CustomerCtrl {
    export class CustomerCtrl {
        static $inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$templateCache'];

        constructor(protected $scope: ICustomerScope,
            protected $http: ng.IHttpService,
            protected $templateCache: ng.ITemplateCacheService) {
            $scope.search = this.search;
            console.log(angular.element($scope).scope());
        }
        public search = (search: any) => {
            debugger;
           var Search = {
                ActId: search.txtAct,
                checkActiveOnly: search.checkActiveOnly,
                checkParentsOnly: search.checkParentsOnly,
                listCustomerType: search.listCustomerType
            };

            this.$scope.customer = [];
            this.$scope.ticket = [];
            this.$scope.services = [];


            this.$http.put('<%=ResolveUrl("/API/Search/PutDoSearch")%>', Search).
                success((data, status, headers, config) => {
                debugger;
                this.$scope.cust_File = data[0].customers;
                this.$scope.ticket_file = data[0].tickets;
                this.$scope.service_file = data[0].services;
            }).
                error((data, status) => {
                console.log("Request Failed");
                });

        }
    }
    var customerapp = angular.module("CustomerSearch", []);
    customerapp.controller('CustomerCtrl',["$scope", CustomerCtrl]);

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the cause for "angular is not defined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined) -- Make sure you include the angular script file before running your code

Comment: You can change `customerapp.controller('CustomerCtrl',["$scope", CustomerCtrl]);` to `customerapp.controller('CustomerCtrl', CustomerCtrl);` because you are using `$inject`

Comment: Happy to see ur reply @Brocco,But it's not working still the same error

Comment: Mico, can you show how you are loading angular?

Comment: @DavidSherret i have just given the reference path of the JSCrip

Comment: <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.js"  />
     <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/Scripts/angular.min.js"  /><dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.routes.js"  />
      <dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Portals/_default/Customer.Search/app/app.module.js"  />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this Question by changing the sequence of my java script references.
as :-

```
1.jquery-latest.js
2.app.module.js" 
3.Controller.js" 
4.Interface.js" 
5.angular.js" 
6.angular.min.js" 
7.app.routes.js"
```