# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to test an example with AngularJS to evaluation expressions but  an error is show:  'Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined' (anonymous function)
i have two files :  index.html and expression.js
index.html:

```
<script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/expression.js"></script>
         <script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-controller="ExampleController" class="expressions">
  Expression:
  <input type='text' ng-model="expr" size="80"/>
  <button ng-click="addExp(expr)">Evaluate</button>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="expr in exprs track by $index">
     [ <a href="" ng-click="removeExp($index)">X</a> ]
     <code>{{expr}}</code> => <span ng-bind="$parent.$eval(expr)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

expression.js :

```
angular.module('expressionExample', []).controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  var exprs = $scope.exprs = [];
  $scope.expr = '3*10|currency';
  $scope.addExp = function(expr) {
    exprs.push(expr);
  };

  $scope.removeExp = function(index) {
    exprs.splice(index, 1);
  };
}]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the cause for "angular is not defined"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this change

```
<script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/expression.js"></script>
```

The reason being your expression.js is dependent on angualarjs framework.
When you do `angular.module` it looks for an interface for configuring the modules. Since expression js is loaded prior to angularjs it is not able to find the interface.

This is equally applicable for other library & framework. If your js file has dependency on library like `jquery` the jquery.js file should be loaded before your custom files

To get rid of such error you can take look at `asynchronous module definition(AMD)` or `CommonJS`.Can also explore module loader like `webpack`

Answer (score 1):

Scripts you include are loaded in the order that they are included. So you need to include `angular.min.js` before you include the `expression.js` file, as that depends on the `angular.min.js` file.

```
<script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/expression.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running that script before you include Angular itself.

That's not going to work.

Comment: so haw can i correct ? i am a  beginner at angularjs

Comment: You can't use Angular before running the Angular script file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is into the file 'index.html'

**First:** the include of source of 'angularjs.min.js' must be written before the include of 'expression.js'

**Then :** you should specified the ng-app='expressionExample' ; for exemple into the balise html

*This is the correction*:

```
<html ng-app='expressionExample'>
 <script src="/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/angular.min.js"></script>

  <script src='/home/mohamed/Desktop/AngularJS/expression.js'></script>       

<div ng-controller="ExampleController" class="expressions">
  Expression:
  <input type='text' ng-model="expr" size="80"/>
  <button ng-click="addExp(expr)">Evaluate</button>
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="expr in exprs track by $index">
     [ <a href="" ng-click="removeExp($index)">X</a> ]
     <code>{{expr}}</code> => <span ng-bind="$parent.$eval(expr)"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</html>
```