# How to Create playlist in angularjs audio app?

Tags: angularjs, audio

I had created a angular audio app. i want to display play list in it . Using directive to trigger play pause and other operations. Please help me to create play list here.

my main html is

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <title> AUDIO</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ng-cool-audio.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ng-cool-audio.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #f5f5f5;
      font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    }
    
    .main {
      width: 800px;
      margin: 100px auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <div class="main">

    <ng-cool-audio source="source2"></ng-cool-audio>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

my html template is

```html
<div class="ng-cool-audio-container">
  <audio>
    Your browser seems to be upgraded! :)
  </audio>
  <div class="ng-cool-audio-preview">
    <div class="ncv-audio-left">
      <div class="ncv-img-container">
        <img ng-src="{{audio.cover}}" alt="Photo">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ncv-audio-right">
      <div class="ncv-audio-right-top">
        <div class="ncv-header">
          <div class="ncv-header-title">{{audio.author}}</div>
          <div class="ncv-header-subtitle">{{audio.name}}</div>
          <div class="ncv-audio-sound">
            <i class="fa fa-volume-up" ng-show="!isMuted" ng-click="volumeOff()"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-volume-off" ng-show="isMuted" ng-click="volumeOn()"></i>
            <input type="range" max="10" min="0" value="5">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ncv-audio-right-bottom">
        <div class="ncv-audio-controls">
          <i class="fa fa-backward" ng-click="playBackward()"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-play" ng-click="play()"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-pause" ng-click="pause()"></i>
          <i class="fa fa-forward" ng-click="playForward()"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="ncv-progress">
          <progress class="ncv-progress-bar" max="100" value="{{progressValue}}"></progress>
        </div>
        <div class="ncv-time">
          <span class="ncv-current-time">{{currentTime}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <h4> PLAY LIST </h4>

    <div class="col-lg-3" ng-repeat="song in source2">
      {{song.audio.name}}

    </div>

  </div>




</div>
```

app.js is

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app', [
      'ngCoolAudio'
    ])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.source2 = {
        audio: [{
            author: 'Dr. SPB',
            cover: 'images/about.jpg',
            src: 'audio/AADI ANAADI-SPB.mp3',
            name: 'AADI ANAADI'
          },
          {
            author: 'Dr.RAJ',
            cover: 'images/about.jpg',
            src: 'audio/BHAVA SAAGARADA AALADI-DR.RAJ.mp3',
            name: 'BHAVA SAAGARADA AALADI'
          },
          {
            author: 'Dr.RAJ',
            cover: 'images/about.jpg',
            src: 'audio/CHARAKULAAMBUDHI CHANDIRA-DR.RAJ (2).mp3',
            name: 'CHARAKULAAMBUDHI CHANDIRA'
          },
          {
            author: 'S.JANAKI',
            cover: 'images/about.jpg',
            src: 'audio/DHYANA MAADUTHIRU-S.JANAKI .mp3',
            name: 'DHYANA MAADUTHIRU'
          },
          {
            author: 'OM',
            cover: 'images/about.jpg',
            src: 'audio/Om Namahshivaya.mp3',
            name: 'OM NAMAHSHIVAYA'
          }

        ],
        config: {
          autoplay: false,
          loop: true
        }
      }
    })
})();
```

audio directive is

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('ngCoolAudio', [])
    .directive('ngCoolAudio', [
      '$timeout',
      '$sce',
      function($timeout, $sce) {
        return {
          restrict: 'AE',
          scope: {
            source: '=source'
          },
          replace: true,
          templateUrl: 'html/audio.html',
          controller: ['$scope', '$element', function($scope, $element) {
            //check source file
            if (!$scope.source || !$scope.source.audio) {
              throw new Error('Source seems not to config right!');
              return;
            }

            var container = $element[0].querySelector('.ng-cool-audio-container');
            var audio = $element[0].querySelector('audio');

            var volume_range = $element[0].querySelector('.ncv-audio-sound input[type="range"]');

            var $audio = angular.element(audio);

            $scope.audio = {};


            //private method
            var calCulateTime = function() {
              var secs = parseInt(audio.currentTime % 60);
              var mins = parseInt((audio.currentTime / 60) % 60);

              // Ensure it's two digits. For example, 03 rather than 3.
              secs = ("0" + secs).slice(-2);
              mins = ("0" + mins).slice(-2);
              return mins + ':' + secs;
            }

            var calCulateProgress = function() {
              var percent = (100 / audio.duration) * audio.currentTime;
              return percent;
            }

            var generateAudio = function(audio) {
              if (!audio.src) {
                throw new Error('Not found src in your audio config');
                return;
              }
              $audio.attr('src', audio.src);
              $scope.audio.cover = audio.cover || 'http://7xj610.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/29ce98b4349b72c2778d2f82823159b06f98f8bc.jpeg';
              $scope.audio.author = audio.author || 'Unknow';
              $scope.audio.name = audio.name || 'Unknow';
            }

            $scope.currentTrack = 0;
            $scope.jumpInterval = 10;
            $scope.init = function() {
              $scope.currentTime = '00:00';
              $scope.progressValue = 0;
              $scope.isPlaying = false;
              $scope.isMuted = false;
              $scope.setInterface($scope.currentTrack);
              $scope.addEvents();
            };

            $scope.setInterface = function(index) {
              var isArray = angular.isArray($scope.source.audio);
              if (isArray) {
                $scope.audioCollection = $scope.source.audio;
                generateAudio($scope.audioCollection[index]);
              } else {
                generateAudio($scope.source.audio);
              }

              if ($scope.source.config) {
                if ($scope.source.config.autoplay) {
                  $audio.attr('autoplay', 'autoplay');
                  $scope.play();
                }
                if ($scope.source.config.loop) {
                  $audio.attr('loop', 'loop');
                }
              }
            };

            //toggle play pause
            $scope.play = function() {
              audio.play();
              $scope.isPlaying = true;
            };

            $scope.pause = function() {
              audio.pause();
              $scope.isPlaying = false;
            };

            //toggle mute
            $scope.volumeOn = function() {
              audio.muted = false;
              $scope.isMuted = false;
            };

            $scope.volumeOff = function() {
              audio.muted = true;
              $scope.isMuted = true;
            };

            //backward forward
            $scope.playBackward = function() {
              //here jump to pre song
              if ($scope.audioCollection && $scope.audioCollection.length > 0) {
                $scope.currentTrack -= 1;
                if ($scope.currentTrack < 0) {
                  $scope.currentTrack = $scope.audioCollection.length - 1;
                }
                $scope.init();
                $scope.play();
              } else {
                var toTime = audio.currentTime - $scope.jumpInterval;
                if (toTime < 0) {
                  audio.currentTime = 0;
                } else {
                  audio.currentTime = toTime;
                }
                $scope.currentTime = calCulateTime();
                $scope.progressValue = calCulateProgress();
              }
            };

            $scope.playForward = function() {
              //here jump to next song
              if ($scope.audioCollection && $scope.audioCollection.length > 0) {
                $scope.currentTrack += 1;

                if ($scope.currentTrack > $scope.audioCollection.length - 1) {
                  $scope.currentTrack = 0;
                }
                $scope.init();
                $scope.play();
              } else {
                var toTime = audio.currentTime + $scope.jumpInterval;
                if (toTime > audio.duration) {
                  audio.currentTime = audio.duration;
                } else {
                  audio.currentTime = toTime;
                }
                $scope.currentTime = calCulateTime();
                $scope.progressValue = calCulateProgress();
              }
            };

            //skip progress
            $scope.skipProgress = function(e) {
              //update time and progress
              var target = e.target;
              var offsetX = 0;
              if (!e.pageX || !target.offsetLeft) {
                offsetX = e.offsetX ? e.offsetX : e.layerX;
              } else {
                offsetX = e.pageX - target.offsetLeft;
              }
              var pos = offsetX / target.offsetWidth;
              audio.currentTime = pos * audio.duration;
              $scope.currentTime = calCulateTime();
              $scope.progressValue = calCulateProgress();
            }


            $scope.addEvents = function() {

              //time update
              // progress update
              audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
                $scope.currentTime = calCulateTime();
                $scope.progressValue = calCulateProgress();
                $scope.$apply();
              }, false);

              audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
                //auto play next
                if ($scope.audioCollection && $scope.audioCollection.length > 0) {
                  $scope.playForward();
                }
              });

              //angular seems dont support input[range] stuff so let's do it event
              volume_range.addEventListener('change', function() {
                audio.volume = parseFloat(this.value / 10);
              }, false);
            }

          }],
          link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
            scope.init();
          }
        }
      }
    ])
})();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined

Comment: what exactly is this?

Comment: ng-repeat is not working in template html file audio.html