# Why include angular-translate give error in debugger?

Tags: android, angularjs

I try build IONIC android app and give function multi language with angular-translate and this link to download angular-translate [https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate/releases/tag/2.15.2](http://link) But i have error when include plugin like this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at angular-translate.min.js:6
    at angular-translate.min.js:6
    at angular-translate.min.js:6
```

I don't know how to fix it ? please help me to solve this problem
thanks

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18044522/4056108)

Comment: it work thank, but have some warning : Tried to load angular more than once.

Comment: I am not 100% sure however there is a protected [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22595878/4056108) on stackover flow you can have a look at

Answer (score 0):

Do work with angular package u need require AngularJS the first.
U can download it from https://angularjs.org/