# After publishing ASP.NET MVC application not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis

I've developed an application using ASP.NET MVC + AngularJS. after publishing my application in another PC's IIS server, my application not working properly. When I click the login button following the output display in the URL bar **`'SubmitButon=ok'`**.

[image]

I can't understand this error because of AngularJS error or something else error? Can anyone please tell me how can I solve this error.

**Note:** I developed this application on a Windows Server 2012 PC. I hosted that PC's IIS server and application works properly. But this error occurs when I trying to host application in another PC.

Browser console display following errors

[image]

Comment: Check if there is any `console errors` in your browser developer tab.

Comment: @stom Please check updated question. I post console errors

Comment: It seems you have not placed angular script file in correct position, Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined), It may help you.

Comment: issue is not related to .net mvc or angular, you have to place the reference script in the right position. angular.js itself is missing it seems

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV How can I do it

Comment: open your developer console and check whether you can see the reference files there.