# AngularJS is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm starting to study in AngularJs at the beginning level. My project is used in the Spring Boot framework. I get an error message: "ReferenceError: angular is not defined". I have already created app.js which is a defined angular variable, but it is still an error.

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute']);
app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.title = "Welcome";        
}]);
```

welcome.jsp:

```
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Create an account</title>
        <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" ng-controller="mainController">
            <c:if test="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name != null}">
            <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="${contextPath}/logout">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </form>

            <h2> {{ title }} ${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} | 
                <a onclick="document.forms['logoutForm'].submit()">Logout</a></h2>
            </c:if> 
            {{ title }}         
        </div>


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to move App script below angular one in script declaration

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the cause for "angular is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18044519/what-is-the-cause-for-angular-is-not-defined)

Comment: Also be aware that bootstrap.js does not play well with angular.js

Answer (score 1):

Move your script below

```html
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Create an account</title>
        <link href="${contextPath}/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>

        <!-- move it here -->
        
        <script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had to spend a lot of time with this problem.

Comment: Glad to help you :) It is important to place scripts in order you want to load them

Answer (score 1):

Add `angular` script before your `app.js`.

Since your `app.js` uses `angular` object, it must be already defined. `angular` scripts does that job, so it must be loaded before any `angular` code.

Try below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I had to spend a lot of time with this problem.